# Deserialization error in XML document(2,2)

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an xml document that validates through xmlvalidate.  I've pared the file down to a bare minimum, but am getting the above error.

```
        string tteFilepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        tteFilepath += "\\" + "SkeletonNetwork.xml";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NetworkDescriptionDTO));
        NetworkDescription networkDescription = new NetworkDescription();
        NetworkDescriptionDTO ndDTO = new NetworkDescriptionDTO();

        try
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(tteFilepath, FileMode.Open);
            ndDTO = (NetworkDescriptionDTO)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
            fs.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception parseEx)
        {

            String exception = parseEx.Message;

        }
```

The bare XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<nd:NetworkDescription
    xmi:version="2.0"
    xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:buf="http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/Buffering/5.4.0"
    xmlns:c="http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/Constraint/5.4.0"
    xmlns:flows="http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/Flows/5.4.0"
    xmlns:logical="http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/Logical/5.4.0"
    xmlns:nd="http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/5.4.0"
    xmlns:sync="http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/Synchronization/5.4.0"
    xmlns:t="http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/Triggers/5.4.0"
    xmlns:topo="http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/Topology/5.4.0"
    name="tte_demo"
    enableDynamicRouting="true"
    createUnknownDefaultRoutes="true"
    ctMarker="//@flowMarker[name='ctMarker']">
</nd:NetworkDescription>
```

I've tried leaving off the version at the end of the ns paths, among other tweaks and fiddles with the xml file, to no worthwhile effect.

The error is:

"There is an error in XML document (2, 2)."

InnerException is:

"http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/5.4.0'> was not expected."

The class for NetworkDescriptionDTO was created with the xsd.exe tool using appropriate xsd files.

Anyone have any ideas?

Below is a snippet of the class.

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/5.4.0")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/5.4.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class NetworkDescriptionDTO : NamedElementDTO
    {

        private object[] items2Field;

        private bool enableDynamicRoutingField;

        private bool createUnknownDefaultRoutesField;

        private string ctMarkerField;

        public NetworkDescriptionDTO()
        {
            this.enableDynamicRoutingField = false;
            this.createUnknownDefaultRoutesField = false;
        }
```

Comment: Can we see the type you're using? Does it declare the XML namespace correctly? Namespaces are everything in XML. Specifically, `NetworkDescriptionDTO` should have an `[XmlRoot(...)]` that indicates the name and namespace

Comment: I've added a snippet of the class into the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue was the ElementName parameter of the XMLRootAttribute.  My theory is that the class name and the xml node name being different caused the issue.  Adding the ElementName to the XMLRootAttribute  enabled the serialization to complete without exception.

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/5.4.0")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "NetworkDescription", Namespace = "http://www.tttech.com/Schema/TTEthernet/Network_Description/5.4.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class NetworkDescriptionDTO : NamedElementDTO
    {

        private object[] items2Field;

        private bool enableDynamicRoutingField;

        private bool createUnknownDefaultRoutesField;

        private string ctMarkerField;

        public NetworkDescriptionDTO()
        {
            this.enableDynamicRoutingField = false;
            this.createUnknownDefaultRoutesField = false;
        }
```